# How to exclude a specific file with Apache FileFilterUtils?

Tags: java, apache, file, filter, copy

Please consider the following folder structure:

```
src
  |_text1.txt
  |_text2.txt
  |_content
      |_text1.txt
      |_text2.txt
```

How do I have to design an **org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.IOFileFilter** to exclude the *src/text1.txt* and *src/text2.txt* but keeping *src/content/text1.txt* and *src/content/text2.txt* ?

Currently my filter looks like this:

```
IOFileFilter filter = FileFilterUtils.and(
                    FileFilterUtils.notFileFilter(FileFilterUtils.nameFileFilter("text1.txt", IOCase.SENSITIVE)),
                    FileFilterUtils.notFileFilter(FileFilterUtils.nameFileFilter("text2.txt", IOCase.SENSITIVE))
            );
FileUtils.copyDirectory(new File("src"), new File("dst"), filter);
```

But the code snippet above obviously doesn't copy the two text files within the *src/content/* folder either (which I want to have copied)... Btw. the names of the text files are **not** changeable.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK commons io doesn't provide something like a `PathFileFilter` thus you'd have to add your own filte here.

`NameFileFilter`, as the name implies, only checks for the file name, i.e. the path is not relevant.

Providing your own filter should not be that hard. I'd suggest subclassing `AbstractFileFilter` or `NameFileFilter` here. Subclassing `NameFileFilter` might be considered a somewhat dirty approach, since you're not only checking the names, but would just require you to override the `accept()` methods:

```
public boolean accept(File file) {
   return accept( file.getPath() );
}

public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
  //use normalize to account for possible double separators or windows paths which use \
  return accept( FilenameUtils.normalize( dir.getPath() + "/" + name ) );
}

protected boolean accept( String path ) {     
   for (String nameSuffix: names) {
     if (caseSensitivity.checkEndsWith( path, nameSuffix )) {
         return true;
     }
   }
   return false;
}
```

Then you'd use it like `FileFilterUtils.notFileFilter(new PathFileFilter("/text1.txt"))` etc.

Alternatively you could provide a set of patterns and check those:

```
private Set<Pattern> pathPatterns = new HashSet<>();

PathFileFilter(String... patterns) {
   for( String p : patterns ) {
     pathPatterns.add( Pattern.compile(p) );
   }
}

protected boolean accept( String path ) {     
  for (Pattern pattern : pathPatterns) {
    //separatorsToUnix is used to convert \ to /
    if ( pattern.matches( FilenameUtils.separatorsToUnix( path ) )) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Usage: `new PathFileFilter("(?i)(.*/)?test[12]\\.txt");` or `new PathFileFilter("(?i)(.*/)?test1\\.txt", "(?i)(.*/)?anothertest2\\.txt");`

Short breakdown of the regex:

- `(?i)` makes the expression case-insensitive, leave it out for case-sensitive matches
- `(.*/)?` means that if the filename is preceeded by anything it must end with a slash, i.e. this would match `some/path/test1.txt` but not `someothertest1.txt`.
- `test[12]\\.txt` would be the file name, here meaning `text` followed by `1` or `2` and finally `.txt`